# How can I optimize my code so, it can run effectively?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to optimize my code so, it runs faster. This is part of the code but what it basically does is takes a bunch of data from a website, finds the specific value and then prints it in the console.log.

My goal is to optimize my code so, that my code and process time are shorter

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.table-dark-row td b'))
  return tds.map(td => td.innerText)
}); //fetches the data from an element from a website

so = 'Shares outstanding:' + result[4]; 
sf = 'Shares Float:' + result[10];
shof = 'Short Float:' + result[16];
sr = 'Short Ratio:' + result[24];

console.log(so, sf, shof, sr); //await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: So what is the goal? Optimize it or make the goal cleaner? Those two don't always go hand-in-hand. Also, it's unclear what you mean by "fetching multiple times", there's no trace of that in your code.

Comment: By optimized if you mean clean.... then in the function you can do just this: `return document.querySelectorAll(".table-dark-row td b").map((td) => td.innerText);`

Comment: Apologies, I made the edits, I want to optimize my code so, process time is a lot shorter, I believe putting array is better but I'm unsure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't fetch the page multiple times when you reference a `result[i]`, so no worries about include it multiple times.

You could refactor the [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) so it will be written more concisely. *Note:* you won't really notice the performance difference between the two, it will only look cleaner. `$$eval` runs the same JavaScript methods under the hood:

> [...] runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to pageFunction.

So you could use it like this:

```js
const results = await page.$$eval('.table-dark-row td b', tds => tds.map(td => td.innerText))
```

If you experience poor performance it should be another part of the script.